# unilateral weighted shift bounded if and only if weights are bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have a question regarding the unilateral weighted shift $S$ on a complex seperable hilbert space $H$. I tried to prove that $S$ is bounded if the weights $w_{n}$ are bounded by some number $C$. For an ONB $(e_n)$ the shift $S$ is defined as follows: $Se_n = w_{n}e_{n+1}$

Here's my approach:

$\mathrm{Let}\ N\in\mathbb{N},\ \mathrm{with} \ x  = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_ne_n \ \mathrm{where} \ c_n \mathrm{ \ are \ the\ fourier }\ \mathrm{coefficients,} \mathrm{\ it} \ \mathrm{holds},$

$\|S(\sum_{n=1}^{N} c_ne_n)\|^2=\|\sum_{n=1}^{N} c_nS(e_n)\|^2=(\sum_{n=1}^{N} c_nS(e_n), \sum_{m=1}^{N} c_mS(e_m))=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\sum_{m=1}^{N} c_n\overline{c_m}(w_ne_{n+1},w_me_{m+1})=\sum_{n=1}^{N}|c_n|^2|w_n|^2\leq C^2\sum_{n=1}^{N}|c_n|^2\leq C^2\|x\|^2$

Since we have this for inequality for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$ we obtain

$\|Sx\|^2=\|S(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_ne_n)\|^2\leq C^2\|x\|^2$

Hence, $S$ is bounded.

I wasn't quite sure if this works out. In particular I am not sure if I can argue that if the inequality holds for all N, that it holds for the infinite sum. so, does this work or not, and if so, why? thanks in advance

Comment: The standard shift $$S(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots, )=(0,x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots )$$ is bounded as $\|Sx\|=\|x\|.$ The multiplication operator $$M(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots )=(w_1x_1,w_2x_2,w_3x_3,\ldots )$$ is bounded by $C.$ Hence $SM$ is bounded by $C.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works. You have shown that $\|Sx\|\leq C\,\|x\|$ for all $x$ in a dense subspace $H_0$. For a general $y$, fix $\varepsilon>0$ and find $x\in H_0$ with $\|y-x\|\leq\varepsilon$. Then $\|x\|\leq\varepsilon+\|y\|$ and hence
$$
\|Sy\|\leq\|Sy-Sx\|+\|Sx\|\leq\varepsilon+C\,\|x\|\leq\varepsilon+C\varepsilon+C\|y\|. 
$$
As this can be done for any $\varepsilon>0$, you get that $\|Sy\|\leq C\,\|y\|$.

Comment: thanks, that helped a lot! I haven't thought about the density of the ONB somehow...

as for the last part you said, it kinda sounds like circular reasoning, doesn't it? I can't just assume S to be bounded in order to drag the Operator into the infinite sum and with that show that S is bounded. Or am I misunderstood?

Comment: Yes, you are right. My bad. I'm just used to think of $S$ as the usual (bounded) shift.

Comment: to be fair, this argument (the one i started and you completed) still lacks a lot. With the definition I stated, S is only defined on the span of the ONB, hence it's a little dodgy to just say S(x) = S(lim yn) with yn in the span of the ONB (that's why @RyszardSzwarc s approach still needs some arguing too, i think). it works, but one would still have to argue uniqueness of that continuation. In hinsight I suppose the best way to prove it is to use the theorem which gives you a unique bounded continuation on the whole space if you're a bounded linear operator on a dense closed subspace.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from defining $$S(\sum_n c_ne_n)=\sum_n\omega_nc_ne_{n+1}.$$ It is trivial to check that if $|\omega_n|\leq C$ for all $n$ then $S$ is well-defined in the sense that the image still lies in $H$.